# Change ActionBarCompat title color but not other texts color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using last release of support library (V21) which include material themes (under Theme.AppCompat name) and I want to put ActionBar title in white. I tried to achieve it by using textColorPrimary (as it's shown [there](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar)) attribut in my custom theme

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orange_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>

    <!-- This attribut set text color --> 
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

With this I got a white actionbar title **but all other text (textview, edittext) were white too...**

Is there a way to change only actionbar title color with recently released features or the only way is to use a custom style for action bar, just like it was the case with Holo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to invert the text color only in the Action Bar.